# Getting this error "AttributeError: 'music' object has no attribute 'music_queue'" when trying to do anything with my list

Tags: python, discord.py

```
class music(commands.Cog):
 def init(self, client):
   self.client = client
   self.music_queue = []

cog_ext.cog_slash(name='play', description='play music')
 async def play(self,ctx,song):

   self.music_queue.append(song)

   print(self.music_queue)
```

```
AttributeError: 'music' object has no attribute 'music_queue'
```

Comment: Your `init` should be called `__init__` in order to run when a `music` object is instantiated. You need to instantiate a `music` object before `play` is run, or run your `init`, because otherwise `music_queue` will never have been defined at that point. Also your indentation is all messed up so it would be nice if that was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this isn't a discord.py related question as it doesn't support slash commands. Secondly, it's supposed to be `@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='play', description='play music')`. Thirdly, the indentation makes it so that the decorator (and thus the command) wouldn't be a part of the class.

```py
class Music(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client=client
        self.music_queue=[]

    @cog_ext.cog_slash(
        name="play",
        description="plays a song (probably)"
    )
    async def play(self, ctx, song):
        self.music_queue.append(song)
        return
```